# Union of intervals in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe in Spark.

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 140396 | 2002-06-18 | 2003-06-18 |
| 140396 | 2007-07-29 | 2015-07-29 |
| 140396 | 2008-02-05 | 2010-02-05 |
| 140396 | 2009-01-18 | 2010-01-18 |
| 140396 | 2013-01-19 | 2021-08-30 |
| 140396 | 2017-05-15 | 2021-08-30 |

I have to analyze the date ranges to get other date ranges without intersections between them, but keeping the full range of dates. Result:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 140396 | 2002-06-18 | 2003-06-18 |
| 140396 | 2007-07-29 | 2021-08-30 |

---

Other example could from:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 140396 | 2002-06-18 | 2003-06-18 |
| 140396 | 2007-07-29 | 2015-07-29 |
| 140396 | 2014-02-05 | 2016-02-05 |
| 140396 | 2017-05-15 | 2021-08-30 |

to

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 140396 | 2002-06-18 | 2003-06-18 |
| 140396 | 2007-07-29 | 2016-02-05 |
| 140396 | 2017-05-15 | 2021-08-30 |

Keep in mind that there will be other users with their dates, so the problem is partitioned with a window by id.

Would someone wise know how to solve this?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    
val df = Seq(
(140396, "2002-06-18", "2003-06-18"),
(140396, "2007-07-29", "2015-07-29"),
(140396, "2008-02-05", "2010-02-05"),
(140396, "2009-01-18", "2010-01-18"),
(140396, "2013-01-19", "2021-08-30"),
(140396, "2017-05-15", "2021-08-30"),
(140397, "2002-06-18", "2003-06-18"),
(140397, "2007-07-29", "2015-07-29"),
(140397, "2014-02-05", "2016-02-05"),
(140397, "2017-05-15", "2021-08-30")
) toDF ("id", "start", "end")

val windowSpec1 = Window.partitionBy(col("id"))
                        .orderBy(col("start"), col("end"))
                        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow - 1)

val windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy(col("id"))
                        .orderBy(col("start"), col("end"))
                        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

val result = df.withColumn("left_edge", max(when(col("start") < max(col("end")).over(windowSpec1), null).otherwise(col("start"))).over(windowSpec2))
               .groupBy(col("id"), col("left_edge"))
               .agg(min(col("start")).alias("start"), max(col("end")).alias("end"))
               .select("id", "start", "end")
               .orderBy("id", "start")

display(result)
```

Result:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 140396 | 2002-06-18 | 2003-06-18 |
| 140396 | 2007-07-29 | 2021-08-30 |
| 140397 | 2002-06-18 | 2003-06-18 |
| 140397 | 2007-07-29 | 2016-02-05 |
| 140397 | 2017-05-15 | 2021-08-30 |

Reference:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Range_aggregation

Answer (score 1):

**You can group by your dataframe by `id`, cast the result to a `KeyValueGroupedDataset` and then perform [merge overlapping intervals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/) algorithm**

You first need to define `case class` representing a line of your dataframe:

```scala
case class Line(id: Int, start: String, end: String)
```

And then use it in the main part:

```scala
import sparkSession.implicits._

dataframe
  .groupBy("id")
  .as[Int, Line]
  .flatMapGroups((id, grouped) => grouped.toSeq.sortBy(_.start).foldLeft(Seq.empty[Line])((acc, line) => (acc, line) match {
    case (Nil, line) => Seq(line)
    case (x::xs, line) if x.end >= line.end => x::xs
    case (x::xs, line) if x.end < line.end && x.end >= line.start => Line(id, x.start, line.end) +: xs
    case (xs, line) => line +: xs
  }))
  .orderBy("id", "start")
```